# Is there a way to have intellisense working for classic-asp custom classes in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp-classic, intellisense

First, this has never worked before, so it is not specifically related to VS 2008.
The problem : when you have custom asp classes in separate files that you include in a "main" asp script, you won't get intellisense in Visual Studio.

Example : 
CUser.asp

```
<%
Class CUser
   Public Sub Create()
   Public Sub Remove()
End Class
%>
```

Main.asp :

```
<!--#include file="CUser.asp"-->
<%
Dim user : Set user = new CUser
user.Create
%>
```

You don't get any Intellisense when you type "user.". If I do the same INSIDE CUser.asp, after the "End Class" statement, then it works.

Do you know any way to make this work consistently in all asp files ?

Idea : I thought of maybe generating a custom "intellisense file" that I could feed to Visual Studio with all the symbols and comments for my functions, subs, etc... but didn't find too much information about this topic. Any leads here ?

Comment: I believe Eclipse would have more information about performing such an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible.

Comment: Do you have a link or doc indicating that this is not possible ?

Comment: it is not a feature so it is not documented. But no, I have no confirmation from MS or other source that says it is not supported in VS. I was hoping for it before as I previously developed in ASP (now doing Rails).

Answer (score 1):

The lack of "real compiled" classes in ASP Classic was one of the major reasons for me to switch to ASP.NET long ago... sorry to tell you that. If you like classes and objects I would strongly recommend you to do a "language switch" of the big ones. :o)

I've also switched from VBscript to C# as I did some C/C++ before we got ASP.

But my major reason for deciding c# instead of VB.net is that most hardcore examples seems to be written in c#, secondly the switch between javascript (clientside) and c# (serverside) is pretty usefull when you are busy.

Lastly, Flash/Actionscript 3.0 is becomming more and more objectoriented too and this also builds on the ECMA standards for scripts.

Sorry for all this OT text, but I think you might be ready for the "big switch" :o)

Regards

Comment: I'd LOVE to switch to .NET, but when you have a quite large codebase in classic asp, switching is not always an option, at least for now. But I'm still hoping ...

Comment: If you are using javascript, that is not "real compiled", you can get intellisense from other files as long as you add them to the intellisense settings of visual studio.  You can do it with jquery and other external libraries, and with local js files that you include everywhere.  So, no "real compilation" is not a reason to not get intellisense from include file in "classic asp" web site.